# Stiff ODEs in python

Tags: python, ode

Could you please give some general advise or suggest where to look regarding the following problem?

In *Python* I'm trying to solve a system of roughly 100 nonlinear complex stiff ODEs. I evolve my equations in time to find a steady-state solution for only one variable. It turns out that for some parameters solutions are very smooth, but for other - the solutions oscillate strongly and become unphysical at some point in time (drop below zero, while physically it's not possible).

I use the integrator *zvode* with a method *bdf*:

```
    r = ode(diff).set_integrator('zvode', method = 'bdf', atol = ..., retol 
       = ...)
    r.set_initial_value(initial, t0)
    while r.successful() and r.t < tend:
        output = r.integrate(r.t+dt)
```

I've tried to make my time step smaller, I tried to vary *atol* and *retol*, but nothing really helps, i.e. sometimes I can fix these numerical difficulties, but for some other parameters - cannot.

Comment: Can you give an example of your system reduced to less than 10 equations? Did you try to use `lsoda` which is behind `odent`? There are other packages that provide a larger range of implicit methods.

Comment: I am afraid it's not so simple to write down this system here, however, a reduced one can be found in _arXiv:1611.03342_, page 4. I've also rewritten my system with real variables and so tried to use _dvode_, but I get an arror        "_no integrator name match with 'dvode' or is not available_"

Comment: You can use any real method if you wrap the ODE function in compleifying the input state vector `z = y[:len(y)/2]+1j*y[len(y)/2:]` and separate the real components for the return value `dy = numpy.concatenate((dz.real, dz.imag))`. And similarly in the further evaluation of the output.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the advantage of using a real method over a complex?

Comment: *but what is the advantage of using a real method over a complex?* – You can use a different method that may be more capable of handling your problem. Also, if you encounter the same issue with two different methods, it’s an indicator that the issue does not arise from the method from the problem (model, parameters) themselves.

Comment: Also: What indicators do you have that your problem is actually stiff? As you are using an adaptive integrator, most stiff problems just would lead to the integrator detecting this problem and complain about the step size becoming too small. In particular an unphysically negative solution suggest that there is a problem with the model, your implementation that actually allows this to happen. (Of course none of this can be said for certain, but without any details, it’s impossible to help you. Moreover, if you actually have such a problem, it’s not a programming issue, but for [scicomp.se].)

Comment: Finally: “Your” time step is not the same as the integration time step. If you want to control the latter, use `max_step`. There is no parameter `retol`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.

I am pretty sure that this issue arises from the parameters 
because for quite a huge range of parameters I don't have 
any problem at all and reproduce previously known results.

By stiff I only mean that in some range of parameters my 
solutions are unstable and some variables get very large 
while others stay small (ratio around 10^10)

I am not a computer scientist, so I can hardly see any 
diference between computer science and programming.

Comment: *By stiff I only mean that in some range of parameters my solutions are unstable and some variables get very large while others stay small (ratio around 10^10)* – Could still be the expected behaviour, e.g., if some attractor loses stability. — *I am not a computer scientist, so I can hardly see any diference between computer science and programming.* – I was taking about [scicomp.se], not [cs.se]. There is an import difference between the two.